# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start a process against a different domain

Tags: c#, .net, process

We have a scenario where we need our users to be able to launch SQLServer and authenticate into it using a different domain than they are currently logged into. So to clarify the way this is setup:

1. User arrives at the office and logs in to the corporate domain (lets call it LOCALDOMAIN for simplicity)
2. They wish to connect to our remote database on a different domain (lets call it REMOTEDOMAIN)
3. First they launch the VPN tool which establishes the VPN tunnel to REMOTEDOMAIN (this is all tested and works great)
4. But if they launch SSMS by default it will only allow Windows Auth via LOCALDOMAIN, the option to select REMOTEDOMAIN is not even available

What we discovered is that running this from the command line will work:

```
RUNAS /user:REMOTEDOMAIN\AUserName /netonly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe
```

it will prompt with the message "Enter the password for REMOTEDOMAIN\AUserName:" and if you supply the correct password, SSMS will be launched and can connect to the remote dbs. However, when I try to do the same thing in C# with a nicer interface around it, I get "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password", here is my code:

```
System.Security.SecureString password = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach(char c in txtPassword.Text.ToCharArray()){
    password.AppendChar(c);
}
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
procInfo.Arguments = "/netonly";
procInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"; ;
procInfo.Domain = "REMOTEDOMAIN";
procInfo.Verb = "runas";
procInfo.UserName = txtUsername.Text;
procInfo.Password = password;
procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procInfo);
```

I tried the username with and without the domain pre-pended but neither works. Anyone ever tried to do something similar? thanks

Comment: Be careful with this. The instance of SSMS that is opened by this may not have permission to anything locally that a "User" of the local machine would have. Including any mapped network drives that have not been made persistent.

Comment: Adding as a comment because I dont want the wrath of answering a question incorrectly. SSMS will shut itself down if there is a file that it recovers. I have the same scenario as you, what resolved it for me was to open SSMS manually deal with the recovered files then proceed as normal

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the following lines:

```
// Not passing /netonly to SMSS, it was passed to RunAs originally.
procInfo.Arguments = "/netonly";
// Again, SMSS is not getting the verb, it's being run
procInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Basically, you're passing the `/netonly` parameter to SMSS, whereas on the command line, you're running `runas` *not SMSS*.  Same with the verb, you're not running `runas`.

The call to `Start` should succeed at that point, as you'll be pointing to the correct executable with the correct credentials.

Comment: I tried that but I get the same error, I can kinda see what you are saying though, but there are many examples of running exes via elevated priveleges that use runas as the verb

Answer (score 0):

I've done something that may be related.  I login to one domain and try to get a directory listing of a shared folder on a different domain.  To do this, I use LogonUser and Impersonate.  The code looks like the following (sorry, I don't have an SQL server to try your exact scenario)...

```
public class Login : IDisposable
{
    public Login(string userName, string domainName)
    {
        _userName = userName;
        _domainName = domainName;
    }

    string _userName = null;
    string _domainName = null;

    IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
    IntPtr dupeTokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);
    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = null;

    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "LogonUser")]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "LogonUser")]
    public static extern bool LogonUserPrompt(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, IntPtr lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle,
        int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

    public void AccessShare(string password)
    {
        tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool returnValue = LogonUser(_userName, _domainName, password,
            LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
            ref tokenHandle);

        if (false == returnValue)
        {
            int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
        }

        // Use the token handle returned by LogonUser.
        WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);
        impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
    }

#region IDisposable Members
    public void  Dispose()
    {
        impersonatedUser.Undo();

        // Free the tokens.
        if (tokenHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(tokenHandle);
    }
#endregion
}
```

I've used this with Directory.GetDirectories(UNCPath) where the path leads to a machine on another domain and it works there.  I have not yet tried it for implementing a "runas".

I call it like so...

```
using(var login = new Login("myname","mydomain))
{
    login.AccessShare("mypassword");
    // do stuff
}
```

Maybe you can adapt it to your problem.  LMK

Comment: thanks for the reply, I actually tried something very similar to that (I tried your code too) but it doesn't seem to do it with my scenario for whatever reason

Comment: that gives me: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the various user impersonation code samples I could find. None of them worked.

Finally, I came up with the following code. It executes `cmd.exe` with the `/C` argument, which `Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates` . The command that I execute is `runas /netonly ...`

### Caveats

Unfortunately, the password has to be typed manually. My next step is to investigate sending key stokes to the `process`. I tried redirecting standard input and writing to it, but it didn't work. I read somewhere on SO that most password prompts only accept input directly from the keyboard.

Also, when SSMS opens, the **Connect to Server** dialog will show your current domain\username, but it will authenticate using the one you gave to `runas`.

Finally, if your AD account is locked, you won't get an error until you try to connect to SQL Server. I neglected to copy down the error message that I received, but it did not mention the account was locked.

### Code

```
    public static void RunAsNetonly(string username, string domain, string exePath)
    {

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

        psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        psi.Arguments = $"/C runas /netonly /user:{domain}\\{username} \"{exePath}\"";            
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;

        var process = Process.Start(psi);

        // not sure if this is required
        process.WaitForExit();

    }        
    
    // usage example
    public static void RunSSMS()
    {
        RunAsNetonly("walter", "domain123", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe");
    }
```